# jquery.datatables not displayed correctly

Tags: c#, css, mvc.jquery.datatables

I'm working on a ASP .Net MVC tutorial and should implement `jquery.datatables` on a page. They do appear and work but they are messing up the layout. it looks like the filter controls, the table, and the pagination tools ar all on one line. Also the sort direction indicators are not displayed:
[image]

So I tried playing around with the css-styles and found out that it is related with the `.form-inline` class:

```
.form-inline {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

If remove that class the controls are displayed "better". Meaning they are still not spread over the whole table with:

[image]

I've also checked if the css for the `jquery.datatables`are bundled to reach the client, and they do. I have also updated `jquery` and `jquery.datatables`. Any hints what goes wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `flex-direction: column` to `.form-inline`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't change anything...

Comment: You need to show us the css for the item holding the table and the filters - preferably the direct parent css, but what happens if you change row for column  and nowrap for wrap in that css you show? `flex-flow: column nowrap`

Comment: well that's quite a lot of code... would it maybe help if you have access to it?